# Use Python to read data written by Java

Tags: google-app-engine

Currently, due to migration process, I need to use Python to read data, which are previously written by Java.

Here is one of the data written by Java - [UserDatabase](http://jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/jstock/jstock-cloud/file/2cdcddfb1d18/src/org/shuwnyuan/cloud/UserDatabase.java)

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
UserDatabase user_database = new UserDatabase(email, date, checksum, version, content_list, total_byte);
pm.makePersistent(user_database);
```

I was wondering, is there any proper way for me, to use Python to read the old data, which is written by Java previously?

As far as Python as concern, Python will expect some "hidden" field from the entity. For instance, `key_name`. The information is not found in Java's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - just create models in Python that match the structure of the data written by the Java app (or observed in the datastore viewer), or use `db.Expando` to define a class that accepts any fields.

Python requires no 'hidden fields' - `key_name` is a way of specifying the name field of the entity's key when it's being created.